# Odd behavior of long Document annotation type in UIMA Ruta script

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I have the following types:

- `SpecialDocument` inheriting from `uima.tcas.Annotation` (or `uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation`, ideally) with a feature `specialFeature` of type `uima.cas.String`
- `SomeAnnotation` inheriting from `uima.tcas.Annotation`

I have a rule that is successfully firing:

`Document{ -> MARK(SpecialDocument)};`

I know it is firing because I get a `SpecialDocument` annotation with the `Document`'s text out of it.

But when I try to do *anything* with it moving forward, i.e. use it in subsequent rules, the rules do nothing.

For the *very same rules* that are not firing when I create a `SpecialDocument` from an existing `Document`, they *do fire* when I create a `SpecialDocument` from something else!!!

So, for instance:

```
Document{ -> MARK(SpecialDocument)}; // creates a SpecialDocument
SomeAnnotation -> SpecialDocument; // creates a SpecialDocument

// This sets specialFeature for every SpecialDocument EXCEPT the one created ƒrom Document.

SpecialDocument{ -> SETFEATURE("specialFeature", "whatever")};

// This marks a new annotation of SomeOtherAnnotation, again for every SpecialDocument EXCEPT the one I care about!!!

SpecialDocument{ -> MARK(SomeOtherAnnotation)};
```

**EDIT** I've noticed that this seems to be more about the length of the annotation than the type - when I do short documents, it works as expected.

What on Earth is going on here? Is this a bug or am I going nuts?

Comment: In my experience, this is most likely caused by the filtering settings. Does your document start or end with something invisible, e.g., a space or linre break? Could be that there is a special handling of actually invisible document annotations. You can also test it by using this rule before: RETAINTYPE(WS);

Comment: btw, I would not recommend to use annotations derived from DocumentAnnotation, and also not to create them with ruta rules. DocumentAnnotation is rather assumed to be a singleton in UIMA and is created when the document text is set.

Comment: In case the first comment does not help, can you provide an exemplary text where this problem occurs?

Comment: @PeterKluegl thanks for the help. I'll let you know in a bit but I will say that I was able to get it to work after removing just the very last character of the annotation. I didn't realize Document was a singleton but that makes sense. The way inline rules and forEach works, I would almost think it is kind of an abstract class that gets realized in different forms depending on context in the script